# What does `FlutterPluginRegistrant` do?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Of recent times, I have been looking into running flutter from inside an already built app (in iOS). I was curious to know what does FlutterPluginRegistrant do?

Furthermore, I want to know if the flutter-framework, generated by building for iOS, can be imported inside other frameworks of my application (custom created frameworks)?

Answer (score -1):

The first part of your question can be answered with a google [search](https://api.flutter.dev/objcdoc/Protocols/FlutterPluginRegistrar.html).

The second is a bit confusing. If you are asking about running Flutter inside an existing iOS application, it's not only [possible](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app), but Alibaba has now created something to make it even easier: [Flutter-boot](https://github.com/alibaba-flutter/flutter-boot)